# Accessing quicktype JSON object in flutter

Tags: json, parsing, flutter, quicktype

I have a JSON string that is mapped with code generated in quicktype, into an instance of "Pax". Quicktype generated some 4000 rows of code mapping this so Im happy and confident that it works to some extent. I now want to print a specific small part of this sea of data to start with. It's a string located at pax.instructions.id.

```
final String paxRaw = response.body;
final Pax xa = paxFromJson(paxRaw);
```

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    Pax paxFromJson(String str) => Pax.fromJson(json.decode(str));
    
    String paxToJson(Pwa data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
    
    class Pax {
      Pax({
        this.greeting,
        this.instructions,
      });
    
      String greeting;
      List<Instruction> instructions;
    
      factory Pax.fromRawJson(String str) => Pax.fromJson(json.decode(str));
    
      String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());
    
      factory Pax.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Pax(
        greeting: json["greeting"] == null ? null : json["greeting"],
        instructions: json["instructions"] == null ? null : List<Instruction>.from(json["instructions"].map((x) => Instruction.fromJson(x))),
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "greeting": greeting == null ? null : greeting,
        "instructions": instructions == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(instructions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
    }
```

I want to access a data member of the list *instructions* that is called *id*.

```
print(xa);
```

Returns console:

```
I/flutter ( 4535): Instance of 'Pax'
```

I know instructions is a list, but how do I acess the string that is called id in this list? My best guess is
`print(xa.instructions<id>);` but it doesn't work. There's clearly something built, but I can't figure out how to inspect "xa" on a debug level (in android studio). Helpful for guidance.

**UPDATE, still not working**

```
  Future<Pax> _futurePax;

  Future<Pax> getPax() async {
    debugPrint("getPax start");
[...]
    http.Response response = await http.get(baseUri);
    debugPrint('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    debugPrint(response.body);
    return Pax.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _futurePax = getPax();
    });
  }
```

```
Container (
                child: FutureBuilder<Pax> (
                    future: _futurePax,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      debugPrint("Futurebuilder<Pax> buildpart");
                      debugPrint("Test snapshot content: ${snapshot.data.toString()}");
                      debugPrint("Test snapshot error: ${snapshot.error}");
                      debugPrint("Test snapshot has data (bool): ${snapshot.hasData}");
                      debugPrint(snapshot.data.instructions[0].id);
                      return Text("Snap: ${snapshot.data.instructions[0].id}");
                    }
              ),
              ),
```

Console:

```
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
I/flutter ( 5126): Futurebuilder<Pax> buildpart
I/flutter ( 5126): Test snapshot content: Instance of 'Pax'
I/flutter ( 5126): Test snapshot error: null
I/flutter ( 5126): Test snapshot has data (bool): true

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<Pax>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<Pax>#a2168):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

Comment: Can you share the json?

Comment: Sure, https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.nytimes.com&category=PWA&strategy=mobile&locale=us

Comment: I'm not sure what is quicktype so I could be missing something but the json you shared does not have `instructions` property.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/ just paste the json and it generates dart code to map it. @ClaudioRedi

Comment: Seems like quicktype is generating a parent level that doesn't exist.

Comment: I removed the first level in the generated code and printed captchaResult, but still same response.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really confused. `greetings` and `instructions` are part of the "sample" json that quicktype shows by default in https://app.quicktype.io/. The json you shared is totally different and it doesn't contain `instructions` property... where's the json containing `greetings` and `instructions`?

Comment: Haha, I misunderstood the "instructions" for paste here: :D Funny one, have been stressing me for days now. Type a short answer and you'll get the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`greetings` and `instructions` are part of the "sample" json that [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) shows by default.

The [json you shared](http://googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://%E2%80%A6) is totally different and it doesn't contain `instructions` property so it will never find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<Pax> getPax() async {
....//call function body
print(response.body)
return Pax.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}
```

Then you can retrieve any of this fields from a builder method. Create a variable in your build method and pass the result of the function above to it.

```
Future<Pax> _futurePax;
_futurePax = getPax();//can be used in initState
```

the use the builder method

```
FutureBuilder<Pax>(
        future: _futurePax,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
//use a listview/gridview or handle list indexes in any way you'd prefer
//in the list you can get snapshot.data.instructions[index].id 
   })
```

Comment: I updated with this but it didn't seem to work, any clue? I added the new code.

Comment: was your problem fixed from the answer by @Claudio

Comment: Yes. There was a pasting mistake in app.quicktype.io that generated parent classes that didn't exist, so when I removed those classes it worked.